# ASP.NET Basic Counter for HTML Scrollbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm developing a scroller for featured articles on an existing site for a client. (I did not develop the site).

I need to add a counter to the below HTML so that each time the repeater element is called, each item has a unique "data-caption" value.

Below is my code, your help is greatly appreciated!

```
          <asp:repeater id="rptNews" runat="server">
    <itemtemplate>


      <img src="getImage.asp?img=<%# Container.DataItem("image").Trim()%>&w=600&h=600" data-caption="#htmlCaption5" />




    <span class="orbit-caption" id="htmlCaption5"><strong><a href="/<%# Container.DataItem("url").Trim()%>/"><%# Container.DataItem("title").Trim()%>:</a> </strong><a href="/<%# Container.DataItem("url").Trim()%>/">Read More</a></span>



    </itemtemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from memory and hasn't been tested, but it should give you an idea:

```
 <asp:repeater id="rptNews" runat="server">
     <itemtemplate>
         <img src="getImage.asp?img=<%# Container.DataItem("image").Trim()%>&w=600&h=600" data-caption='<%# String.Format("#htmlCaption{0}", Container.ItemIndex) %>' />
         <span class="orbit-caption" id='<%# String.Format("#htmlCaption{0}", Container.ItemIndex) %>'><strong><a href="/<%# Container.DataItem("url").Trim()%>/"><%# Container.DataItem("title").Trim()%>:</a> </strong><a href="/<%# Container.DataItem("url").Trim()%>/">Read More</a></span>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Basically:  replace your string "#htmlCaption5" with `<%# String.Format("#htmlCaption{0}", Container.ItemIndex) %>'`